# Is there any alternate DVD with complete language pack?

Tags: alternate

I'm looking for an alternate DVD (like the alternate CD, but with complete language packs). Is there one?

Comment: Removed the part that will solicit discussions.

Comment: changed "Desktop DVD" to "alternate CD"

Answer (score 1):

You can find alternate DVD at  [Here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads)

GO to section

> DVD images with complete language packs

Comment: No, there are just LiveDVD's. That's why I asked.

Comment: It contains complete language packs that you need,  you can install system with using live DVD.

Comment: That is the problem @K.KPatel ... he probably wants the alternate for a reason ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is no alternate DVD.

The intended usage for the DVD is to install extra languages for the desktop and as an extra benefit some more desktop software (like inkscape, GIMP, Pitivi and a more complete LibreOffice). The focus of the DVD is therefor the desktop.

The method to use is to use the alternate CD and afterwards install the extra languages (should be possible to do with `apt-get`). Since there is a path to getting those extra languages it seems redundant to also create an alternate DVD.

Comment: Thinking in that way, it is also just redundant to have a Desktop DVD...

Comment: And the alternate cd is also focused on the desktop, but using it there are setups you can't create with the live CD/DVD. So there is a point for creating an alternate DVD.

Comment: No, the alternate cd has its uses. Less and less, granted but there are some usecases where you need a text based installer. The DVD itself is only usefull when there is no internet connection. But I would pose creating your own custom installer would be a lot more useful.